# Dropdown menu button [not dropdown menu] won't trigger click event after the first time

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have a bootstrap 4 dropdown button, and I have a click listener attached to that button itself. When I click the dropdown button to open the menu,, the first time button onclick handler is getting hit. Then menu opens fine and if I click outside the menu closes as the default behavior of bootstrap dropdown.

But from then if I click the button to open the menu again, the button onclick handler not getting hit afterward.
I need to add this handler so that before each occasion of menu-open I can set some values within the dropdown menu items and then show it.

this js fiddle represents the issue
[Link to JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/sovilomixa/edit?html,js,output)

How to solve this issue. Is it a problem of event bubbling?
Any way to overcome this?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.MainButton', function(e){
  alert("opening dropdown");
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div >
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle MainButton" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">11111111</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">22222222</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">33333333</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you needing to change dropdown options each time right before displaying it? I mean, what's the use case? You may change this behaviour and actually render proper options when firing another event; would this solve your issue?

Comment: Its necessary because in my case the drop down menu items have some values which can be changed by users when they click apply for each field. So if someone opens menu and changes some value,but without applying closes the menu and again opens, it showing the changed value. So i need to populate last stored correct values in the menu items. Thats why i need to get a event whenever drop-down btn is clicked so i can update data before it shows. Im curious just why it doesn't get captured in event handler from the second click!!